# Laravel: Local Dayname is not displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have got a problem with the local dayname.

Code from index.blade.php

```
{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($case->created_at)->formatLocalized('%A, %e %B %Y') }}
```

and the output should be e.g.: `Sonntag, 08.04.2018`
but it returns`Sunday, 08.04.2018`

I also added to my AppServiceProvider.php following code:

```
Carbon::setUTF8(true);
Carbon::setLocale('de');
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the locale in `config/app.php`? Look for `'locale' => 'en',`

Comment: ```'locale' => 'de'``` is in there

Comment: Ok, try setting the locale first with the native PHP `setLocale` - For example,  `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set your env locale first

```
app()->setLocale('de');
Carbon::setLocale('de');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
```